# Access resources login protected with Rails and Flex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

i'm trying to figure out how i can handle login protected actions in RoR (Ruby on Rails) with Flex without using weborm or rubyamf remoteobject.
I'm in the situation where i have to fill a datagrid with results of an HTTPService request after i log in correctly into my application. 
Can anyone suggest me the way to accomplish that?

Kind regards, 
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely recommend using the [RestfulX Framework](http://wiki.github.com/dima/restfulx/getting-started-with-restfulx-and-ruby-on-rails).  They have created a pretty fully featured time tracking application called [Pomodo on Rails](http://github.com/dima/pomodo_on_rails), and the [LoginScreen](http://github.com/dima/pomodo_on_rails/blob/master/app/flex/pomodo/components/login/LoginScreen.mxml) for it shows how to do authentication with Flex and Rails, using the Rails [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) plugin on the backend.  They had to do a lot of stuff to keep track of session and some other things that were pretty tricky.  It works very well and will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Pomodo isnt the application in example with Flexible Rails? Thanks for the suggestion, but i've to apply those changes without modify too much the existent project, btw he's using amf, and i'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Flexible Rails was produced a few years ago.  Pomodo on Rails started from that book, but it's significantly modified, and it's using XML instead of AMF.  I'd just use it as a reference if nothing else.

Comment: Well, as i see, in the link code you give me, in LoginScreen, in the function login() they call session.amf, but maybe is just a formalism?